# Find out which display belongs to which adapter?

Tags: directx, direct3d, gpu, slimdx

I'm working on a SlimDX apps which works for multiple display. The apps will occupy the selected display, and it's selection is input via commandline, as int. I then use `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[selection]` to find out about the bound, and display my apps "fullscreen" on that display.

Now, to optimize performance, I need to select which gpu adapter to initialize the Direct3D's device. How do I find out which gpu adapter is powering the selected display?

Since Each gpu adapter might have one to two display connected, I can't use the display number.

I'm utilizing Direct3D10. I don't mind solution in Direct3D9.

Worse case would be to let user select display and adapter via commandline, but I prefer a fool prove method.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both D3D10 and D3D11 use DXGI for managing details like this. The Factory interface you create lets you get a list of adapters installed on the system. Each adapter can have one or more outputs, which you can enumerate from the Adapter interface.

This will get you a list of Output interfaces, which have a Description property that contains, among other things, a Rectangle of the output's bounds as well as an IntPtr handle to the monitor on which it is running.

I don't think the Winforms Screen class exposes the underlying native pointer, which is why we provide the SlimDX.Windows.DisplayMonitor class to serve as a replacement for the Screen class. You can use this to determine the particular details of the display and choose the right adapter for your needs.

Comment: I was expecting Output as properties, that's why I didn't find it. That's for the solution and info on SlimDX.Windows.DisplayMonitor, that's very helpful

Comment: I love it when Google already has the answer to my question and it's on Stackoverflow :) I'm finding SlimDX very useful btw. Thanks for making it.